# WebRtcNs_Process input buffer changed from int16* to float*

Tags: webrtc

I have been using an earlier version of webrtc code. Today, I fetched the latest code and it broke my build:-(. It appears that WebRtcNs_Process now takes a "float" type buffer instead of "int16" type buffer. There may be a good reason to do so. However, this also seems to have broken the chain of operations.

Typically, you first call WebRtcNs_Process and feed the output of this method to WebRtcAecm_Process. In the latest version, the output of WebRtcNs_Process is a float type buffer but the input to WebRtcAecm_Process is a int16 buffer. Seems like now I have to write extra code to convert float buffer to int16 buffer.

Also, on most platforms, the output from the mic is int16 type buffer. There is additional code I have to write to convert this int16 value to float so that I can pass it to WebRtcNs_Process.

I am wondering if I missed something. Regards.